# transform Map<Integer, Double> to Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>

Tags: dictionary, tuples, java-8, iterable

I'm stuck with data transformations in Java-8...

Somebody knows how to transform `Map<Integer, Double>` to `Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>`, or even
`Map.Entry<Integer, Double>` to `Tuple2<Integer, Double>`?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a two-element tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map<>` has a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()` method. This gives you a `Set` of entries you can iterate over.

If you want to iterate over `Tuple2<Integer, Double>` objects, you have to convert the `Entry` objects. To do so, you can e. g. transform your `Set` into a `Stream`:

Step by step:

```
Stream<Entry<Integer, Double>> myEntryStream = myMap.entrySet().stream();
Stream<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> myTuple2Stream = myEntryStream.map(entry -> new Tuple2(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

or simply

```
Stream<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> myStream = myMap.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> new Tuple2(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

To iterate over this, you can do

```
Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> it = myStream::iterator;
```

or just

```
for (Tuple2<Integer, Double> item: (Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Double>>) myStream::iterator) {
    // do sth with item
}
```

If your `Tuple2`, whatever it is, has a constructor which takes a `Map.Entry`, you can even do

```
.map(Tuple2::new)
```

in order to achieve your goal.

Comment: Converting the stream back to an `Iterable` is not much convenient, in the case you want to perform an action in the `for` loop style, it’s easier to use `myMap.forEach((key,value) -> /*your code using key and value*/});` which might even make the use of the `Tuple` class obsolete.

Comment: Holger - No, I use function, which get `Iterable` as parameter.